# Extra Input Tags appear in HTML

Tags: html, angularjs, web-applications

Recently found an issue when trying to write some Automation Tests for a component in my webapp, I am using Anglur for the front end, and am trying to create a type ahead input textbox

```
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label ng-bind="::'ENVIRONMENT' | translate"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : iliCtl.noEnvResults && iliForm.envs.$viewValue !== '' }">
            <input name="envs" id="envs" type="text"
                ng-model="iliCtl.selectedEnv"
                uib-typeahead="env.name for env in iliCtl.environmentData | filter:{name:$viewValue} | limitTo:50"
                typeahead-no-results="iliCtl.noEnvResults"
                typeahead-show-hint="true" typeahead-min-length="0"
                typeahead-on-select="onEnvSelect($item)"
                placeholder="-- Select --" 
                class="form-control">
            <div class="error-class" ng-show="iliCtl.noEnvResults && iliForm.envs.$viewValue !== ''" ng-bind="::'ERROR_207' | translate"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The above code works fine until I inspect the element, the the generated HTML appears to generate two input tags as per image below.

[image: Generated HTML Code]

Any ideas as to why this would be happening, as you can see the Input tags contain mostly the same properties the major differences seem to be styling properties. But I cant see why this would be happening.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, and it isn't a bug as I first assumed.

The Input Tag property `typeahead-show-hint="true"` is responsible for generating the second input box in the HTML, It is used to display a suggested item in the text box.